# How to use setInterval until image not loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am using setInterval for change image on mouse over, I want that set interval call again after or next interval comes after only when image loaded..
 Following is my code:

```
jQuery('.product').on('mouseover',function(){
timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (counter !== 0) {
    time = 2000;
  }
  if (counter === product_images.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  selector.attr('src', 'localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);

  var loadImage = new Image();
  loadImage.src = selector.attr('src');
  loadImage.onload = function(){
     selector.show();
  };
  counter = counter + 1;
},1000);
});
```

What i want that before coming next image using set interval time next image should not be loaded until previous one not loaded... and in that time i want display loading image

How could i do it with jquery promise or by other solution.
Please help me...

One more thing i do not want to called next interval until first image not loaded

Comment: wrap it into function and call the function recursively in `onload` event

Comment: @simon first image is already in my browser..other images i m setting from js.. how its possible to load next image until previous on loaded..

Comment: You should attach the `.onload` first before setting the `.src` property.

Comment: @jack but its repeat next image..before that...

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use `setTimeout()` here so that you can start it only when the current image has finished loading.

Comment: @jack could you provide some code for setTimeout so that i could use it

Answer (score 0):

you can use document.ready

call the function inside document.ready so once the page is completely loaded your function will be called

Answer (score 0):

first Load the images when page is loading in header,then those image will be in browser cache then it works fine,
Just Try this :

```
      if (document.images) {
           img1 = new Image();
           img1.src = "imgpath/image1.png";
           img2 = new Image();
           img2.src = "imgpath/image2.png"";
       }
```